# How to generate recursive shapes like geokone.net using GL.Begin?

Tags: recursion, unity-game-engine, fractals

http://app.geokone.net/ is an open source javascript app for generating shapes (if you can look at it, it's really fast, for 5 seconds, I'm sure you'll get the idea).

It's hard for me to go through it because it's a lot of code, what is the general idea?

also, I need those shapes as GameObject with polygon collider around them (anything from 0 to 20 of them on the screen at the same time, could be different shapes also), is it even possible with GL?

would GL help me? I think GL would be fast for just 1 shape or something (as it's using recursion), but for what I want, I think drawing them in real time to a texture, then using the texture as a sprite would be faster (as I can save the sprite for shapes that are the same), or maybe I should use a shader? any other method that you can think of?

and for the algorithm itself, what is the general idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use GL, look into custom mesh generation with `MeshFilter`. It is required for the colliders anyway.

Meshes have to be updated just once and probably will be faster than any optimisation you proposed. You might need a shader to draw it, though.

As for the algorithm, I'm afraid you have to look into it yourself or hire someone for it. StackOverflow is for helping with issues, not doing the work for you. If you need a hint, look into basic fractals